# Get Row and Column Totals from 2d Array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

I wanted to know how to get row and column totals from a 2D array in Excel. This is a fairly common thing to do but I couldn't find an answer to it by searching on row and column totals so I thought it would be worth posting it as a question.

Supposing I wanted to find the lowest column total and highest row total in the following array which is in cells A1:D3:-

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12
```

my initial thoughts were along the lines of

```
=min(A1:D3*(column(A1:D3)={1,2,3,4}))
```

but this kind of simple approach doesn't work. I remembered reading that you had to use mmult in some of these situations and have seen advanced formulae using them but couldn't quite remember how. I shall try and answer my own question but other suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `MMULT` as you mentioned. The following should work with your setup:

Smallest column

```
=MIN(MMULT({1,1,1},A1:D3))
```

Largest row:

```
 =MAX(MMULT(A1:D3,{1;1;1;1}))
```

*Note how many 1s in the array - for the rows calc you need a 1 for each column (i.e. 3) and vica versa for columns. Also note the order of the arrays - it won't work the other way around*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to mmult to deliver either a column array or row array containing the required totals, then use can use MAX, MIN or any other aggregate function to get the value you require.

**Column totals**

```
=MIN(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:D3))^0,A1:D3))
```

**Row Totals**

```
=MAX(MMULT(A1:D3,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D3))^0))
```

So the idea is that you create a single-row array {1,1,1} and multiply it by the 2D array to end up with an array {15,18,21,24} and take the minimum value from it.

Or create a single-column array {1;1;1;1} and multiply the original array by it to end up with an array {10;26;42} from which you get the maximum value.

Remember that mmult works like the matrix multiplication you might have learned at college where for each cell it works across the cells in the corresponding row of the first array and down the cells of the corresponding column in the second array multiplying each pair and adding them to the total. So the number of columns in the first array must always equal the number of rows in the second array.

These are, as @Scott Craner reminds me, array formulae that have to be entered with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: FWIW: aren't these array formulas that need to confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter.